# How to combine two fields to be displayed as options in a dropdown menu using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu "Names". Right now, Im populating it with the firstName of employees. The first names of the employees is the data which is added at run time. Now I want to display the options in the dropdown as "(firstName) (lastName)" Is there a way to do this using jquery. Im able to retrive both the firstName and lastName from the database.

Current Jquery Code for the dropdown:

```
$('.employeeName').prepend("<option value=''></option>").val('');
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
if(data[i].firstName)
$('.employeeName').append('<option>' + data[i].firstName  + '</option>');
}
```

Comment: `'<option>' + data[i].firstName + ' ' + data[i].lastName + '</option>'`

Comment: Same as @entropic: `$('.employeeName').append('<option>' + data[i].firstName + '  ' +  data[i].lastName + '</option>');`

Comment: Thank you! I feel so silly. I tried all sorts of code except for thinking straight..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's a matter of simply concatenating the strings to which you already have access.

```
$('.employeeName').prepend("<option value=''></option>").val('');
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i].firstName)
        $('.employeeName').append('<option>' + 
            data[i].firstName  + ' ' + 
            data[i].lastName + 
            '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for more efficiency and best practice, try this,

```
var html = "<option value=''></option>";

for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  if(data[i].firstName) {
    html += '<option>' + data[i].firstName  +  ' ' +  data[i].lastName + '</option>';
  }
}

$('.employeeName').append(html);
```